# The pymodbus connection sometimes doesn't respond?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I'm use "pymodbus" lib to connect PLC devices. The device is used Modbus RTU over TCP that devices will return the temperature and humidity of the environment.

map address list

- 0001: temperature
- 0002: humidity

I performed once to get value and it can succeed.
But I'm using while loop sometimes get error.
I don't know why.

code:

```
from time import sleep
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer import ModbusRtuFramer

from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadHoldingRegistersResponse

client = ModbusTcpClient(host='192.168.1.1', port=5000, framer=ModbusRtuFramer)    
client.connect()
while True:
    rr = client.read_holding_registers(0, 2, unit=1)

    if isinstance(rr, ReadHoldingRegistersResponse):
        temp = rr.registers
        print(temp)
    else:
        print('error')
    sleep(1)
client.close()
```

output:

```
> ...
> [189, 444]
> [189, 443]
> [189]
> error
> error
> ...
```

We can see that sometimes the result is obtained normally, sometimes the result is incomplete, and sometimes the result is not available.

What should I do to solve this problem, I want to monitor this device. Thank you.

Comment: I have never seen this. The only real difference I have is not using `framer=ModbusRtuFramer` so perhaps the answer lies in what that does. Certainly for me, it's either a full list or no list (with an Exception thrown), but not a partial read.

Comment: Hi, thank you. If I don't use `framer = ModbusRtuFramer` will get an error.

Comment: Error msg: `AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'`

Comment: Sometimes, the slave device would not be able to process the requests (due to limitations on the read/write buffers) when read very fast (like in this case every 1 sec) and that could result in `ModbusIOException`. Enable debug logs and see what exactly is happening over the socket . I would use a higher interval between polls in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I see this all the time in my pymodbus code. I suspect there's something wrong  with the implementation when doing succesive reads. What I do, is quite simply, to retry the failed read after a slight delay. And that usually gets it working again. Alternatively,  try closing and re-connecting the client and re-attempt the reading. Also try increasing the sleep time. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I add `client.close()` `client.connect()` in the else case. The same problem still occurs.

Comment: Mmm, yes tbh I see it all the time, but in my application is not relevant since I need to read every 5 mins, and I restart the python script to do so. I have seen the isuse, but dissapears in the next run. So, how about that, instead of running in a loop, put it in a cron with x seconds delay, connect-read-store-disconnect

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print what you have in your temp variable in case it's not instance of ReadHoldingRegisterResponse - it may help.

What I use to have sometimes when the device didn't sent the response yet is:

```
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit
```